# The mysqli n8 extension is missing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have the following error when I try to start phpmyadmin.

Mysql is running. Mysqli scripts are working I cannot get on phpmyadmin.

I had this error for a while but I was always able to logon, just after a restart of my lightppd server recently he completly refuses me to logon.

My phpinfo tells me mysqli is running:

```
mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.5.28
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.5.28
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /ffp/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This is my php.ini

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
extension=zlib.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I went to the documentation of phpadmin but no succes.

This is the error (It's in Dutch)

```
De extensie mysqli n8 ontbreekt. Gelieve uw PHP-configuratie te controleren. Bekijk    onze documentatie voor meer informatie.
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try installing the [mysqlnd](http://php.net/mysqlnd) library and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Rocket but I am using FFP and slacker on a Zyxel Nsa310, and I do not know how to reinstall a complete libery. After upgrading/downgrading both php and mysql and updating phpmyadmin I still get the same error. I tried to reconfigure phpmyadmin so I tried typing in: phpmyadmin/index.php and this works on some crazy level of vauge computer science.. mydomain/phpmyadmin does nog work (same error) but phpmyadmin/index.php does. Weird. If someone else knows the answer, I'd be much obliged!!